# Automatic Copy to clipboard when deleting bunch of text

Tags: windows, firefox, notepad++, clipboard

Since some time I noticed an irritating behaviour on my PC (Windows 7).

Whenever i have a bunch of text. Want to copy part of it (to clipboard), and later select remaining text and delete it with either backspace or del button. The selected text before deletion goes to my clipboard.

I mainly notice it in Notepad++ and Firefox.

To copy part of text I have to copy it, paste it to notepad... then delete text and copy again from notpad for further usage.

What kind of sick option is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd> is the shortcut key to cut text to the clipboard. Can it be that your shiftkey is malfunctioning? or that for some other reason, the shift is being pressed when you press the DEL key?

Comment: I was not aware that SHIFT + DELETE was also the `cut` operation.  [CTRL+X or SHIFT+DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251608(v=office.15).aspx).  The fact you taught something earns you a upvote.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, Shift+DELETE is another way to cut, and Shift+INSERT will paste.  I've found that some programs (or web forms) that don't respond to CTRL+V will allow a paste via Shift+INS :)

Comment: It may be, since it does not always happen... but i never noticed writing capitalized letters out of nowhere tho.
But... when I think of it. I quite often select text with ctrl+shift to delete it... maybe then i press del when still holding shift. Will test it.

Comment: Realized what was the bug.

Noteapd++ have functionality that when you press Ctrl + L removes whole line. Probably it counts as well as Shift + Delete.